# How to deletebytes on a file?

Tags: stream, byte

There is a command like file.strem.writebytes()
How do i do a command like that: filestream.deletebytes(150,350) to delete the bytes between that lengthsize.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do it, so you're going to have to come up with a not-so-easy way and code it.

Probably the simplest is to copy the stream without those bytes in it into a new file and then rename the new file on top of the old file. Note that this will invalidate any existing file handles (they'll still refer to the old file) so you'll need to close and re-open them.

Comment: tnx. can you answer me this question, too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62735407/sourcecode-sample-of-vb-net-file-encryptor-and-decryptor and also if there is some way to confuse the bytes order and then return to the original order. for example. 100011011011 to  1101101000110 and then save to original again? tnx